# In MIUI 2.10.12, where do I set it so that I get pop up notifications?

Tags: sms, miui, alerts, popup

This is the first time I'm using MIUI as my ROM and I swear I managed to make it pop out an alert window when someone messages me. Now, however, I can't seem to figure out how to do it again. When I get a message, it just shows up on the status bar above. How do I re-enable it again?